# Recursive node traversal go through whole graph?

Tags: recursion, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve this work problem, but I'm having some difficuly, since I suck at recursion.

My question is: is there a way where I can pick a node in a graph and traverse the graph all the way through back to the same node where I started, but the nodes can only be visited once? And of course to save the resulting edges traversed.

The graph is unweighted, but it is coordinates in a 2D x and y coordinate system, so each coordinate has an x and y value, meaning the edges can weighted by calculating the distance between the coordinates. If that helps...

Comment: Loop through the children of the source node and BFS starting from each one, check if last node is source and all nodes visited

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. Could you expand a bit on the details? But it sounds like you're onto something! Thanks!

Comment: is the graph directed?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037665/7688996) should be helpful

Comment: Moe: no, it's not. And thanks

Comment: It seems like CPT only works if the graph is weighted. My graph is unweighted and undirected. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What you describe looks like very basic BFS search which typically include marking "visited" nodes. For more detailed help and example, post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand, but here is a suggestion: pick a node n0, then an edge e=(n0,n1). Then remove that edge from the graph, and use a breadth-first search to find the shortest path from n1 back to n0 if it exists.

Another suggestion, which might help you to control the length of the resulting path better: Pick a starting node n0 and find a spanning tree T emanating from n0. Remove n0, and T will (hopefully) break into components. Find an edge e=(n1,n2) from one component to another. Then that edge, plus the edges in T connecting the n1 to n0, plus the edges in T connecting n2 to n0, is a cycle with the properties you desire.