# Traverse as many edges as possible between two vertices in a directed graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, directed-graph, graph-traversal

I'd like to find a set of paths from a start node to and an end node so that those paths collectively contain as many edges of the graph as possible.

Or more precisely: Given a directed graph which may contain cycles, and two vertices u and v, I would like to find a finite set P of paths from u to v, such that for any path q between u and v that is not in P, and any edge e in q, there is a path p in P that contains e. The vertices u and v may be the same.

In fact, an almost identical question has been asked: [Directed Graph Traversal - All paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487466/directed-graph-traversal-all-paths), but the very plausible answer has never been accepted or received an upvote, so I was wondering.
That answer involves using a variant of Dijkstra or A* to iterate over all paths between u and v ordered by length.

From [Is there a well-studied optimization to find the shortest path traversing every weighted edge through a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308232/is-there-a-well-studied-optimization-to-find-the-shortest-path-traversing-every/44037665#44037665) it seems that my question is also almost identical to the "Chinese Postman Problem", except I don't need to visit all the edges, just as many as I can, and I'm not interested in shortest paths, just any paths, and my edges are not weighed.

I was thinking of doing something like the first answer. Or perhaps condense the graph using Kosaraju, use straight Dijkstra to find all paths between u and v, and expand the "condensed" vertices by finding all cycles in the strongly connected components. But I haven't really got anywhere.

What would be the best plan to follow?

Comment: Is there some parameter you are trying to optimize?

Comment: Not particularly. I'd just like to solve he problem in a simple way. Polynomial time would be nice of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a case where the set of paths that contain as many edges as possible is smaller than the set of all distinct paths.

[image]

So if you use an algorithm to find all paths, then you will require an extra step to discard paths that do not add more edges.